# Passing values to a database via constructor

Tags: java, sql

I'm creating an application that has a number of input forms, about 22 of them. I'd like to create one class that saves the form data into the database. The forms will only have to get the textfield values via getters and save the values by calling the database class constructor.

**The huddle:**
The database class uses a prepared statement. I'm having trouble passing the part that binds values binto the parameter, the part that looks like:

```
tmt.setInt(1, 35);  // This would set a value such as age
stmt.setInt(2, 'Another value');
```

Could anyone have any ideas on how to go about this?

The variables in the constructor mean:
    String data: The various textfield values
    String table: The specific table in the database where the values will be stored
    String sql: The part that binds values binto the parameter (I mentioned this in "The huddle" above)

Here is the database class:

```
// STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

public class UpdateAndQuerry {

    public static String data;
    public static String table;
    public static String sql;

    public UpdateAndQuerry (String data, String table, String sql) {
        this.data = data;
        this.table = table;
        this.sql = sql;
    }

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "username";
    static final String PASS = "password";

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        try {
            // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            // STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

            // STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            // String sql = "UPDATE Employees set age = ? WHERE id = ?";

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            // Bind values into the parameters.
            stmt.setInt(1, 35);  // This would set age
            stmt.setInt(2, 102); // This would set ID

            // Let us update age of the record with ID = 102;
            int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Rows impacted : " + rows );

            // Let us select all the records and display them.
            sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            // STEP 5: Extract data from result set

            while (rs.next()) {
                // Retrieve by column name
                int id  = rs.getInt("id");
                int age = rs.getInt("age");
                String first = rs.getString("first");
                String last = rs.getString("last");

                // Display values
                System.out.print("ID: " + id);
                System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
                System.out.print(", First: " + first);
                System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
            }

            // STEP 6: Clean-up environment
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {

            // Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            // finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            } // nothing we can do
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } // end finally try
        } // end try

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    } // end main
} // end JDBCExample
```

Comment: I would think you need some kind of mapping from the text field values to the database columns, so could pass in a `Map<String, Object>` where the key was the "field" name and the value was the value to applied to the column...

Comment: "I'm having trouble passing the part that binds values into the parameter"; what exactly are you having trouble with? Are you getting an exception, are you unsure where/how to write the functions where you'll set the query parameters. I can tell you right off the bat that using main like this is the wrong approach. You need to write separate functions for each SQL query.

Comment: Could you have a simple illustration please? Thanks for the reply [MadProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) . I'm quite a Java/ SQL newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the variable nature of data, it's next to near impossible to write a single "overlord" that can do everything.  Sure you could probably set up some sort of mapping and cross mapping between field values and column names/numbers...but that gets messy quick...

A better solution would be to try and force the caller to provide you with valid data if/where possible.

Instead of focusing on a single class to do everything, you could focus on creating a series of classes that did the required work, starting at an abstract level and building up the functionality from there, getting more detailed as you go along...

For example, you could use a [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String first;
    private String last;
    private int age;

    public Employee(int id, String first, String last, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.age = age;
    }

    /* getters and setters */
}

public class EmployeeQuery extends AbstractQuery<Employee> {

    public EmployeeQuery() {
    }

    protected String getTableName() {
        return "Employees";
    }

    protected String getSelectQuery() {
        return "id, first, last, age";
    }

    protected Employee parse(ResultSet rs) {
        int id  = rs.getInt("id");
        int age = rs.getInt("age");
        String first = rs.getString("first");
        String last = rs.getString("last");
        return new Employee(id, first, last, age);
    }

    protected String getUpdateColumns() {
        return "first = ?, last = ?, age = ?";
    }

    protected String getUpdateConstraint() {
        return "id = ?";
    }

    protected void bindValues(Employee record, PreparedStatement stmt) {
        stmt.bindString(1, record.getFirst());
        stmt.bindString(2, record.getLast());
        stmt.bindInt(3, record.getAge());
        stmt.bindInt(4, record.getID());
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractQuery<T> {
    protected abstract String getTableName();
    protected abstract String getSelectQuery();
    protected abstract T parse(ResultSet rs);
    protected abstract String getUpdateColumns();
    protected abstract String getUpdateConstraint();
    protected abstract void bindValues(T record, PreparedStatement stmt);

    public List<T> list() throws SQLException {
        List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>(25);
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = // get connection
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT " + getSelectQuery() + " FROM " + getTableName();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.hasNext()) {
                results.add(parse(rs));
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
            // Close the connection if you need to...
        }
        return results;
    }

    public int update(T record) throws SQLException {
        int result = -1;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = // get connection
            String query = "UPDATE " + getTableName() + " SET " + getUpdateColumns() + " WHERE " + getUpdateConstraint();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

            bindValues(record, stmt);

            result = stmt.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
            // Close the connection if you need to...
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

If that's a little to off from where you want to be, you could create the `AbstractQuery` to have a method that took a query and a `Object` array and simply use `bindObject` to bind the values to the query...

```
protected int update(String query, Object[] values) {
    //...
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
         Object value = values[index];
         stmt.bindObject((index + 1), value);
    }
    //...
}
```

And then in you `EmployeeQuery`, you could have a method that took the actual parameters...

```
public int update(int id, String first, String last, int age) {
    return update(
        "UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET first = ?, last = ?, age = ? WHERE id = ?",
        new Object[]{first, last, age, id});
}
```

For example....

Please note, I've pretty much typed this in directly, so I've not run it through a compiler so there may be some mistakes, but I hope it will help generate some ideas...

Comment: Thank you so much [MadProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer). Let me try and study your answer. It seems really helpful.

Comment: I hope it at leasts seeds some ideas ;)

Comment: This answer is OK in guiding the OP towards better techniques for mapping simple concrete entities, but I'm not sure it really addresses the "39 different forms" usecase he asked about. See my answer below referring to DataForm and DataFormType, for a good design for mapping large dynamic forms.

Comment: @ThomasW *"Sure you could probably set up some sort of mapping and cross mapping between field values and column names/numbers...but that gets messy quick..."* It also doesn't support refactoring well. And because something works, doesn't always make it right ;) - IMHO

Comment: Sure, for concrete entities such as Customer, Product, Employee I'd recommend concrete mapping -- and it's useful to illustrate well-factored JDBC design, though I'd use Hibernate. But there are common usecases for "dynamic forms" in the real world, and we've done customer-configurable at one of my workplaces. I'd probably map these row-per-field, rather than column-per-field -- easier & better for dynamic data than a fixed table-structure. Note that I specified a _Type System_ to provide industrial-strength underpinnings. (Validation, formatting, storage etc.) This is real design.

Comment: Your `Employee` and `EmployeeQuery` example is pretty reasonable, and for concrete entities are a good illustration. The "loose signature" `update(String query, Object[] params)` and `update(int id, String first, String last, int age)` aren't such good design. Not all databases allow _untyped nulls_ to be bound -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,%20java.lang.Object) -- and clanking individual fields of Employee around, is probably not preferable to passing an Employee instance & doing a complete save/update on the ID and version.

Comment: @ThomasW The reason for forcing the calling down an absolute path is to ensure data integrity, at some level.  A method that takes formal parameters dictates the absolute needs of the method as opposed to a method that takes just a `Map`. Yes, I've use `Map`s and even reflection in the past and I find that the fall apart quickly - my experience, especially when you hand them of the API to other developers.  I personally, would prefer an entity object over formalised parameters, but I simply wanted to demonstrate the possibilities...

Comment: I agree that clear & absolute calls are much better for data integrity. But if saving/updating `Employee`, I'd have a signature `save (Employee employee)` which updated all fields -- I've seen a lot of complex & unreliable code which used multiple partial-update methods, and don't really like that pattern.

Comment: @ThomasW *"I'd have a signature `save (Employee employee)`"* would be my preferred method as well

Comment: As for the Map, I'd wrap it in a `DataForm` and apply a type-system to the fields -- viz `DataFormType'. No reflection. Commonality is achieved by extra getters/setters mapping to well-known property names, and/or subclassing DataForm via a TYPE discriminator and implementing an interface. (eg. to provide DueDate.) Given the fact that config & field definitions are determined by the customer & that we've defined a _type system_, it's well-defined & robust. There's nothing really that other developers can do to break it. Thanks for your comments though!

Comment: @ThomasW I appreciate your input! Always nice to see other ideas

Answer (score 1):

'Save' and 'query' should be separate operations/ methods. Your existing design is completely wrong.

You could use a Map to carry arbitrary form-fields around, but you would be better to wrap that in a class (perhaps named "DataForm"?). That way you can attach an ID & Type, header fields such as Name/Title, Date and User, and a Version counter for optimistic locking.

The code that saves & loads these DataForms should probably be separate from the DataForm itself. `load()`, `create()` and `save()` should all be separate operations. Save can distinguish between INSERT and UPDATE by whether a non-zero ID has been set.

You may also need type information for the DataForms, to help with eg. loading into correct types, writing NULLs, and validation. This would be a DataFormType with (at the simplest) a map of FieldName -> Class, or (more useful) a map of FieldName -> DataFieldType.

```
public interface DataFieldType {
    public Class getDataType();
    public int   getSqlType();

    public void storeToDB (Object value, PreparedStatement stmt);
    public Object loadFromDB (ResultSet rs);

    public String formatToUI (Object value);
    public void parseAndValidate (String text, BindingResult errors);  // to work with Spring framework
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the functionlity which you expect you will have to use JAVA Reflection API. Also I would suggest the following approaches

1. Instead of passing String data to the constructor pass a list of Objects.
2. Using reflections identify the type of object it is and accordingly call the setters

Here is the Reflections APIs link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: You could achieve the samething with `interface`s and generics and save the time messing about with reflection

Comment: Thanks [Pratik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1303680/pratik). Let me look at that.

Comment: [@Pratik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1303680/pratik): I didn't know anything about reflections till now. From the surface they seem quite useful and popular. Will start studying them for future use.

Comment: @MadProgrammer i suggested using reflections because according to his question I felt that he wanted to know how to identify the correct bind method to be called. Also since he is newbie to java I did not give away the entire solution and just provided pointers so that he can could implement it on his own and learning

Comment: *"since he is newbie"* would be a good reason not to suggest reflection ;).  While I have no doubt reflection has it places (and I use it from time, time), I'd consider many other solutions before relying on it.  It brings it's own bag of joy and happiness that needs to be considered.  This is not criticism (and sorry if it comes across that way)